# How to use SQL Server Bulk Insert in Kedro Node?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bulk-load, kedro

I am managing a data pipeline using Kedro and at the last step I have a huge csv file stored in a S3 bucket and I need to load it back to SQL Server.

I'd normally go about that with a [bulk insert](https://towardsdatascience.com/use-python-and-bulk-insert-to-quickly-load-data-from-csv-files-into-sql-server-tables-ba381670d376), but not quite sure how to fit that into the **kedro** templates. This are the destination table and the S3 Bucket as configured in the `catalog.yml`

```
flp_test:
  type: pandas.SQLTableDataSet
  credentials: dw_dev_credentials
  table_name: flp_tst
  load_args:
    schema: 'dwschema'
  save_args:
    schema: 'dwschema'
    if_exists: 'replace'

bulk_insert_input:
   type: pandas.CSVDataSet
   filepath: s3://your_bucket/data/02_intermediate/company/motorbikes.csv
   credentials: dev_s3


def insert_data(self, conn, csv_file_nm, db_table_nm):
    qry = "BULK INSERT " + db_table_nm + " FROM '" + csv_file_nm + "' WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV')"
    # Execute the query
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    success = cursor.execute(qry)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close
```

- How do I point `csv_file_nm` to my `bulk_insert_input` S3 catalog?
- Is there a proper way to indirectly access `dw_dev_credentials` to do the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kedro's [pandas.SQLTableDataSet.html](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.SQLTableDataSet.html) uses the [pandas.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method as is. To use this as is you would need one `pandas.CSVDataSet` into a `node` which then writes to a target `pandas.SQLDataTable` dataset in order to write it to SQL. If you have Spark available this will be faster than Pandas.

In order to use the built in `BULK INSERT` query I think you will need to define a [custom dataset](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/07_extend_kedro/03_custom_datasets.html).